# JQuery's .html() sometimes acting weird in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a button:

[image: Preview button]

Now I have a method on that button:

```
function showPreview(event) {
    var button = event.target;

    $(button).empty().html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');

    $.post(
        ...,
        function (data) {
            ...

            $(button).empty().html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Preview');
        }
    );
}
```

Sometimes (rarely) when I click the button in Chrome, it ends up looking like this:

[image: Messed up preview button]

But when I check in the page inspector in Chrome, it reveals that there's only 1 icon and 1 "Preview" string in the button.

I've tested this with other browsers, and none share a similar bug.

Browsers I've tested this with:

- Internet Explorer 11
- Firefox
- Opera
- Safari

I have concluded this to be a Chrome bug, and this is unacceptable behaviour. As you can see I'm already trying to empty the button before adding new content to no avail. Is there any other workaround for this specific problem?

Here's my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/spe0asbo/2/

Please take note that this only happens rarely. It might not happen at all to you.

Comment: Which Version of Chrome..& If fiddle available it'd be better.

Comment: Have you tried doing it withouth the .empty()? Normally if you call .html() it replaces the html present, having no need to use empty(). This bug might be related to .empty part of your code.

Comment: Initially I wasn't using `empty()`, but added it in the hopes it would solve the problem. Removing it proved no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the button an ID and replace `event.target` with the button element itself.

HTML:

```
<button id='btn01' type="button" onclick="javascript:showPreview(event);">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-o"></i> Preview
</button>
```

JS:

```
function showPreview(event) {
    var button = $('#btn01');
    $(button).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $(button).html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-spin fa-spinner"><i>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(button).html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-o"></i> Preview');
        $(button).removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 2000);
}
```

See the JSFiddle link here : https://jsfiddle.net/4h5pehr9/

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why this would solve my problem?

Comment: You got the issue because event.target can sometimes get evaluated to the <i> element inside the button. This is why, instead of replacing the <i> tag, the original HTML gets added into it.

Comment: I see, clicking on the icon makes the event.target the icon instead of the button it is in. Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

It only happened when I double-clicked the button.

Check my changes: https://jsfiddle.net/ag0ztLna/3/

```
function showPreview(event) {
    var button = event.target;
  $(button).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $(button).html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-spin fa-spinner"><i>');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(button).html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-o"></i> Preview');
    $(button).removeAttr("disabled");
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Disabling the button is generally a good idea, but my button gets this problem even if I've refreshed the page and I click the button only once.